# How to obtain links in the following page and store it inside a variable?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

My objective is to extract all the links from a page and store it so that I can design another crawler to extract information from them as well as have an exhaustive list of relevant links.
However, it seems that I am not pointing the crawler to the right direction for extracting those links as I am getting a NULL list.

'''

```
class ArticleSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'links'
    start_urls = [
    'https://abcnews.go.com/search?searchtext=Coronavirus&type=Story&sort=date'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        all_links = response.css("h2.selectorgadget_selected 
                                  a.AnchorLink.selectorgadget_selected::attr(href)").extract()
        yield{'linktext':all_links}
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting empty list because items and their links are loaded by JavaScript.
Press Cntrl + Shift + P when you are in Chrome Dev Tools and execute Disable JavaScript.After that you can see what are getting when Scrapy makes request to url in start_urls.

Fortunately for you script just makes request to API that you can easily mock.Here you can see JSON response from API.

[image]

So you just need to make request to this url in parse method - https://abcnews.go.com/meta/api/search?q=Coronavirus&limit=10&sort=date&type=Story&section=&totalrecords=true&offset=0.
After that all you have to do is parse this response and get url's you need.

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy import Request


class ArticleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'links'

    start_urls = [
    'https://abcnews.go.com/search?searchtext=Coronavirus&type=Story&sort=date'
    ]

    api_url = "https://abcnews.go.com/meta/api/search?q=Coronavirus&limit=100&sort=date&type=Story&section=&totalrecords=true&offset=0"

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    }

    custom_settings = {
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': 'False',
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        # We need this because otherwise Scrapy won't manage Cookies for us.
        yield Request(self.api_url, self.parse_api, headers=self.headers)
    
    def parse_api(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.text)    
        # From data you can get your links
```

Comment: I'm sorry if the question is very noob, but if the info of the website is there in JavaScript then 
1. How does one get the api_url of a webpage?
2. How does one track the JSON response from API like you did?
I am not aware about CSS or Java-script. I am a Python developer and just want to extract the data from the website for a project. @Ferenec Roma

Comment: Usually data that you want to parse is not in JavaScript itself, JavaScript just make request to some kind of API.You can see all requests in Chrome DevTools on Network tab.If my answer was useful for you, please don't forget to mark it so.